# Allow decimal in JQuery code

Tags: jquery

I have the below script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 $(function () {
    $("#<%= txtAmount.ClientID %>").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if (!((key == 8) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```

What i am trying to do is allow the decimal character (.) but prevent all other characters except for numbers so the only allowed characters are numbers and a decimal.

I read up on keycodes for JQuery which states 110, 190 is the decimal character but the above code allows those values, i read up on javascript which has 46 as the decimal keycode but removing that from the code above didnt work either. Could anyone advise?

Comment: Where exactly does it allow 190 ?

Comment: My understanding of this line "if .... (key >= 96 && key <= 105)))" is that it allows characters above 190?? Suppose im wrong since your asking?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there should be an easier way to do that

```
$("#<%= txtAmount.ClientID %>").keypress(function (e) {
    if (!String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[\d.]/)) e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ChB6f/2/)

Comment: This didnt work. Ive have added the script declarations in the original post, in case i am targeting the incorrect version.

Comment: Works in Fiddle but not on my webpage? I tried changing it to version 1.11.0 but that didnt work either.

Comment: @Computer - If it works in the fiddle, but not on your webpage, something is clearly wrong on your end, as it's just a simple regex, not much that could go wrong ?

Comment: This is strange, the keyboard layout restricts the decimal point from the main layout but the numerical layout on the right allows the decimal??

Answer (score 0):

here is a chunk:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which.indexOf('.') != -1 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });


});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9FMZ2/1/)

For your code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%= txtAmount.ClientID %>").keydown(function (e) {
         //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
         if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0  && e.which.indexOf('.') != -1 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            //display error message
            $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                   return false;
        }
    });

   });
```

Comment: Top code allowed all characters where the bottom code almost works but didnt allow the decimal. I have posted the declarations in my original post in case that has anything to do with it.

Comment: my code only allows numbers is'nt that you asked in question?

Comment: No, my requirement was "only allowed characters are numbers and a decimal"

Comment: means you want `.` to be allowed?

Comment: Yes so this is what im after 12.34 but i dont want any characters allowed (i.e. A-Z, a-z) or any special characters (!"£$%$% etc)

Comment: CHECK THE EDIT NOW ITS FINE